# Two questions on measurable sets.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I'm learning about measure theory, specifically measurable sets, and need help with the following two questions:

> $(1)$ For $n \in \mathbb{N}$, let $E_n = \{x \in [0, 2\pi] : \sin x < {1 \over n}\}$. Find $m(\cap_n E_n)$ and $\lim_{n \to \infty} m(E_n)$;
>
> $(2)$ Find the measure of the set $E = (0, 1] \setminus\{{1 \over n} : n \in \mathbb{N}\}$;

Note: $m$ denotes the Lebesgue measure.

---

Since I'm having some difficulties for $(1)$, I am going to share my thoughts for $(2)$.

$(2)$ We know that all intervals are measurable and the measure of an interval is it's length so $(0, 1]$ is measurable with $m((0, 1]) = 1$. Moreover, if we remove the sequence $a_n = \frac{1}{n}$ from the interval $(0, 1]$ my guess is that it's length won't change since we are removing a countable number of disjoint points from $(0,1]$. So, in fine,

$$m(E) = m\big((0, 1] \setminus\{{1 \over n} : n \in \mathbb{N}\}\big) = 1.$$

Is my work correct for $(2)$? I'm sorry for the lack of effort for $(1)$, I tried to come up with an expression for $E_n$ without any success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the steps, and I'll leave all the details for you:

For (1): Note that $\bigcap_n E_n=\left\{x\in[0,2\pi]:\sin x\leq 0\right\}$. You can write this set explicitly.

Then recall the following fact (or try to prove it, if this is not known at the moment):

> If $(X,\mu)$ is any measure space and $E_n$ are measurable sets with $E_1\supseteq E_2\supseteq E_3\supseteq\cdots$ and $\mu(E_1)<\infty$, then $\mu(\bigcap_n E_n)=\lim_n \mu(E_n)$.

Use this for the second part of (1).

For (2) you are correct. More precisely, show that if $A$ is any countable subset of $\mathbb{R}$, then $m(A)=0$ (Hint: first show this for singletons, i.e., $m(\{x\})=0$ for every $x\in\mathbb{R}$, and then rewrite $A=\bigcup_{x\in A}\{x\}$ and use $\sigma$-additivity).

Comment: Given your very helpful answer here's what I found: $\bigcap_n E_n=\left\{x\in[0,2\pi]:\sin x\leq 0\right\} = \{0\} \cup [\pi, 2\pi]$. It follows that $m(\bigcap_n E_n) = m([\pi, 2\pi]) = \pi$. Also, by the proposition you are giving, we immediately find $\lim_n \mu(E_n) = m(\bigcap_n E_n) = \pi$. Is that correct?

Comment: @VonKarYou are right. When you calculate $m(\bigcap E_n)$ you're ignoring $\{0\}$, so I assume you are comfortable with using that countable sets have measure 0